# Sort not sorting lines with a pipe '|' in it correctly

Tags: sort

I am trying to sort some simple pipe-delimited data. However, sort isn't actually sorting. It moves my header row to the bottom, but my two rows starting with 241 are being split by a row starting with 24.

```
cat sort_fail.csv
column_a|column_b|column_c
241|212|20810378
24|121|2810172
241|213|20810376

sort sort_fail.csv
241|212|20810378
24|121|2810172
241|213|20810376
column_a|column_b|column_c
```

The column headers are being moved to the bottom of the file, so sort is clearly processing it. But, the actual values aren't being sorted like I'd expect.

In this case I worked around it with

```
sort sort_fail.csv --field-separator='|' -k1,1
```

But, I feel like that shouldn't be necessary. Why is sort not sorting?

Comment: use `LC_COLLATE=C sort`. Depending on what you're expecting, you may also need `LC_COLLATE=C sort -t'|' -n`

Comment: To sort "csv style" data you may want to use `csvsort` from `csvkit`, which properly handles quoted values.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`sort` is locale aware, so depending on your LC_COLLATE setting (which is inherited from LANG) you may get different results:

```
$ LANG=C sort sort_fail.csv 
241|212|20810378
241|213|20810376
24|121|2810172
column_a|column_b|column_c

$ LANG=en_US sort sort_fail.csv
241|212|20810378
24|121|2810172
241|213|20810376
column_a|column_b|column_c
```

This can cause problems in scripts, because you may not be aware of what the calling locale is set to, and so may get different results.

It's not uncommon for scripts to force the setting needed

e.g.

```
$ grep 'LC.*sort' /bin/precat
      LC_COLLATE=C sort -u | prezip-bin -z "$cmd: $2"
```

Now what's interesting, here, is the `|` character looks odd.

But that's because the default rule for en_US, which derives from ISO, says

```
$ grep 007C /usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common
<U007C> IGNORE;IGNORE;IGNORE;<j> # 142 |
```

Which means the `|` character is *ignored* and the sort order would be as if the character doesn't exist..

```
$ tr -d '|' < sort_fail.csv | LANG=C sort
24121220810378
241212810172
24121320810376
column_acolumn_bcolumn_c
```

And that matches the "unexpected" sorting you are seeing.

The work arounds are to use `-n` (to force numeric sorts), or to use the field separator (as you did) or to use the `C` locale.

Comment: Fascinating. I did see some other hits about localization, but figured that would impact the relative ordering of 24 vs 241, not something like this.

Comment: something extra useful in GNU sort is the `--debug` option, which indicates the key (underlined) used to compare

Comment: running with --debug just underlines the entire line - sort is including the pipe character, it's just set to have no impact because of localization. It's a good feature but didn't help me in this case (I tried :)

Comment: That's exactly why I mentioned it, @user10777668 -- it indicates that `sort` is using the entire line instead of stopping at characters that we assume it is.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to stop. I was expecting it to recognize the pipe character and include that in the sort, therefore treating 24|1 and 241 differently. I'm not sure how --debug would have changed that, and in fact given that it underlines the | seems like it would have actively distracted from the real problem where localization led to the pipe character being ingored

Answer (score 1):

What irritates me is that the `24` doesn't move from its place between the two `241`. The second field starts with a `1`. Trying the sort with a leading `4` in the second field, the `24` is moved down, so I suspect `sort` just ignores the `|` unless told otherwise.
Try `sort -n`...

Answer (score 1):

-n, --numeric-sort
compare according to string numerical value

```
210
23
```

Without the -n, 210 by text is ahead of 23 as it goes character my character.

Comment: You're right, but this doesn't explain the pipe char being different.  The other answers show that because of the locale, the pipe is treated as not there so the next digit is what decides the ordering.