# strange behavior of sort

Tags: sort

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the default coreutils. I notice a particular behavior of the `sort` command which I am not sure how to explain.

Consider the following command:

```
$ cat <<EOF | sort
0-
01-                                    
EOF
0-
01-
```

This output makes sense, because `-` has smaller ASCII value than `1` and thus this output is expected.

However, if I put one more character at the end:

```
$ cat <<EOF | sort
0-T
01-T
EOF
01-T
0-T
```

This output doesn't make any sense to me as I think `0-T` should come first. Why is this happening. What am I missing here? Am I having a wrong expectation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort not sorting lines with a pipe '|' in it correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487458/sort-not-sorting-lines-with-a-pipe-in-it-correctly) (different character, same principle, I'd think)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the collation order of your locale.

The collation order is a set of rules for each locale that allow for ordering of accented letters (for example `ñ` will come after `n` but before `o` in Spanish).

But that's not it, the collation order also states which characters are to be ignored when sorting. For the locale "C", all characters are taken into account, but for "en_US" for example, the dash (U002D) is ignored, as for most other locales, since they inherit the definitions from iso14651_t1_common (under /usr/share/i18n/locales/ in some distributions).

So, the ordering for your first file poses no problem, since when you ignore the dashes you end up with a simple alphabetical comparison:

```
      -- ignore dashes -->      -- sort --> 
0-                          0               0
01-                         01              01
```

When you add the "T", things change, why? Because now, if you ignore the dashes you have to compare "1" and "T" (the first character is the same) and "1" comes before "T":

```
      -- ignore dashes -->      -- sort --> 
0-T                          0T               01T
01-T                         01T              0T
```

So, it is a good idea to always make sure you are using "C"'s rules, using LC_COLLATE=C when sorting.

In your case:

```
$ cat <<EOF | LC_COLLATE=C sort
0-T
01-T
EOF
```

yields:

```
0-T
01-T
```

As you expected.

Comment: Catless note: `<<EOF LC_COLLATE=C sort`.

Comment: Setting locale to C is almost always wrong (when working with international characters). Try `printf '%s\n' oné one oner onf | LC_COLLATE=C sort` to get `oné` after `oner` and `onf`. That is a surprising result in most languages. Not including what a ß should be in German or what a cz should be in Czech.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it may seem annoying. (in a default locale of en_US.UTF-8)

```
$ printf '%s\n' 1 1- 1-a 11- 11-a | sort
1
1-
11-
11-a
1-a
```

The reason is that the `-` is assigned `no weight` to the collate order.

Similar to what a `"` should do:

```
printf '%s\n' 1 \"1\" 1- \"1-\" 1-a \"1-a\" 11- \"11-\" 11-a \"11-a\" | sort
"1"
"1-"
1
1-
"11-"
11-
"11-a"
11-a
"1-a"
1-a
```

As you can see above, all 1 are sorted together, all `11` also. The problem is that `1-a` is sorted more like `1a` than anything else:

```
printf '%s\n' 1-a 1-b 1-c 1a 1b 1c| sort
1-a
1a
1-b
1b
1-c
1c
```

Whether **punctuation** (`-`, `"`, `;` and others) should be included in the collation sort order is controversial. The prevalent view has been that it should not (in non-ASCII locales).

The **common** file for most of Latin languages is `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common`. In that file the `HYPHEN-MINUS` (yes what we, in layman terms, call dash. Unicode U-002D) collation order is set to:

```
<U002D> IGNORE;IGNORE;IGNORE;<U002D> % HYPHEN-MINUS
```

That is, ignore the first three levels of collating.