# Gnu sort - unexpected behaviour

Tags: sort

I am using sort to pre-process some large data files (containing email addresses). But the ordering it produces is not what I expected (and therefore undermines the later processing of the data). Specifically, sort appears to be ignoring punctuation characters.

e.g. (full email addresses truncated for privacy) `sort -u` gives me this:

```
Got this....

aaala
a.abu
a.abu
aacs.
aad19
a.aga
a.agh
aagro
a.agu
aakyl
a.ala
a.ale
aalig
```

When I was expecting this....

```
a.abu
a.abu
a.aga
a.agh
a.agu
a.ala
a.ale
aaala
aacs.
aad19
aagro
aakyl
aalig
```

(the '-n', '-d' and '-g' flags each give the same result).

How do I convince `sort` to sort based on the ASCII/UTF8 character codes?

Comment: related: [What does "LC\_ALL=C" do?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745)

Comment: Similar: [How to sort lines with >> double angle brackets?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/323821)

Comment: Did you consider [locale problems in sort](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487458/sort-not-sorting-lines-with-a-pipe-in-it-correctly)?

Comment: See also: [Sort LC\_ALL=C vs LC\_ALL=C.utf8](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/564303)

Comment: Good shout about LC_ALL, however all the locales currently available on this box exhibit the same behaviour ( C
C.UTF-8
en_GB.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
)

Comment: I don't understand your examples: When I put the first example in a file, both `sort` and `sort -u` give all the `a.` first on my machine, as expected. Why would you think `aacs.` is the third item?

Comment: Yes, I misplaced aacs. when typing this.

Comment: If you get `a.` first then what version of sort are you using? What is your locale setting?

Comment: `LC_ALL=C sort list_of_items` works for me. Does it really not work for you?