# /bin/sort appears to ignore forward slashes in its input

Tags: sort, slash

I'm running Ubuntu 20.0.4.

Consider these contents of the following file (suppose the file is named `input`) ...

```
/zzzzz foo bar
/hij zzz
xyz abc 
/abc 
ijk lmnop
qwer tyuiop 
abc def
```

If I run `/bin/sort input`, I get the following output ...

```
/abc 
abc def
/hij zzz
ijk lmnop
qwer tyuiop 
xyz abc 
/zzzzz foo bar
```

As you can see, the leading forward slash is totally ignored by the sort algorithm. There is nothing in the `sort` man page which says anything about forward slashes being treated in any kind of special way.

But if I replace each of the forward slashes with the `$` character, this behavior does not occur. For example, suppose that a file which is named `newinput` contains these values ...

```
$zzzzz foo bar
$hij zzz
xyz abc 
$abc 
ijk lmnop
qwer tyuiop 
abc def
```

In other words, `newinput` is the same as `input`, except for the fact that `/` characters have been changed to `$` characters. When I do `/bin/sort newinput`, I get these results ...

```
$abc 
$hij zzz
$zzzzz foo bar
abc def
ijk lmnop
qwer tyuiop 
xyz abc
```

As you can see, in this case, the `$` is indeed treated as a normal, sortable character by `/bin/sort`.

So, what's going on here? And how do I cause `/bin/sort` to pay attention to the `/` character?

Thank you in advance for any ideas and suggestions.

**UPDATE**: If I do this under Debian, the sort works properly, both with regard to `/` and `$`.

So, I'm wondering if this behavior might be a "feature" of Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort not sorting lines with a pipe '|' in it correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487458/sort-not-sorting-lines-with-a-pipe-in-it-correctly)    If you do "LANG=C sort ..." then it'll do what you expect.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. Thank you! And I also just now stumbled upon this same knowledge by trial and error. See my "Answer", below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I figured it out!

On my Ubuntu box, I have `LC_ALL` set to `en_US.UTF8`, and on my Debian box, I have `LC_ALL` set to `C.UTF8`.  If I change `LC_ALL` to `C.UTF8` on my Ubuntu box, the forward slash gets sorted as a regular character. And if I change `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF8` on the Debian box, then the slashes get ignored there, also.

So this behavior appears to be an artifact of `en_US.UTF8` encoding.

Is this correct behavior for `en_US.UTF8`?

Anyway, I now know how to work around this "feature" by an appropriate setting for `LC_ALL`.

**PS**: And also, as Stephen Harris pointed out above, setting `LANG` to `C` fixes this issue in the same way as setting `LC_ALL` to `C.UTF8`.

Comment: I'm a sysadmin in the USA, so when I think about sorting (actually "collation order"), I nearly always envision the order in the ASCII character set.  To get results consistent with ASCII, I set `LC_ALL=C`.