# How to sort text file lines in ASCII order?

Tags: linux, text-processing, sort

Let's say I have the following file.txt:

```
foo-a baz
foo bar
foo-c baz
```

If I run `sort file.txt`, I get the same output:

```
foo-a baz
foo bar
foo-c baz
```

Since   (space) is before `-` in ASCII, I expected the output to be:

```
foo bar
foo-a baz
foo-c baz
```

Event if `sort` looks at entire words, I'd still expect `foo` to come before both `foo-a` and `foo-c`.

I've tried `sort -d` (dictionary),  `sort -g` (general-numeric) and `sort -h` (human-numeric) with no success. Is there a way to get the order I want using sort? Otherwise with another basic utility (I know it would be easy to do with python, perl, ruby etc. but I am writing a shell script that needs to be portable).

Comment: Does `LC_COLLATE=C sort file.txt` give you the expected order?

Comment: It does. Wow that was fast. Please make your comment an answer so that I can accept it. Cheers!

Comment: It's pretty well covered in [Sort not sorting lines with a pipe '|' in it correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487469/65304)